# how can get and list entered value in TextInput on react-native?

Tags: react-native, user-controls, textinput

ı want to save and list values that entered in TextInput on same screen react-native.How can ı make dont know. ı want an example code as image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B34Bw.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. use flatlist and array state.
2. On Change of TextInput update state array
3. add  hint extra={this. state} in flatlist, this update flatlist whenever state changes.
   Refer Flatlist from react native doc. it's easy